# build.gradle - Gradle is not able to pull the java files from source

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle is not pulling the java files from sourcesets while running the build.Gradle it gets import statement errors in few classjava files that few import statements are referring to the classjava packages in moduleEJB and some symbol missing errors and few data type depreciation errors

It is a multi-module web application project
My project structure looks like this
Main project
|
|—-moduleEar
|    ’build.gradle’
|—-moduleEJB
|    ‘build.gradle’
|—-moduleWeb
|     ‘build.gradle‘
|
'setting.Gradle'

module web looks like
`moduleWeb
|
|-src
|   ‘at/com
|         ‘lea/web/cntrlls..
|         ‘new/app/rest/..
|          Like this so many folders
|-lib
|-build.gradle

But in eclipse the moduleWeb looks like when imported it
`Java Resources  |           src ‘at.com.lea.web.cntrlls’ ‘at.com.lea.web.printers.cntrls’ . . . . .  . ‘at.com.new.app.rest…’ ‘at.com.new.app.rest…’ . . . . . . . . . Like this so many packages`

I think few of the classes are  have some dependency on moduleEJB

I tried  in many ways
`sourceSets {
main{
java{
src = [‘src’]
include ‘**/*.java’
}
resources {
src = [‘src’]
include ‘**/*.properties’
}
}
}
resources are pulling from Gradle but the java files are not able to pull

And Also tried adding a dependency in dependencies block
implementation project(‘:moduleEJB’)

And add moduleEJB in the moduleWeb->build path->project->add

And add dependency like implementation(dir: "moduleEJB/ejbModule/at/com/", include: "**/*.java")

But still getting the same errors